# if statement never returns true in scala when comparing strings

Tags: scala, if-statement, types

I'm reading text from a text file in Scala. I'm having difficulties with if statements.

```
for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines) {
    if (line.length>7) { 
        println("b1  >" + line(7)+ "<    " + line(0).getType)
        if(line(7)=="#") {
            println("hashtag")
        }
    }
}
```

below is 2 lines from my text file. the first line has 4 spaces followed by many hashtags. the second line is 4 spaces followed by 1 hashtag (the 4 spaces keep getting deleted by stack overflow)

```
##################################################################################################################################################
#
```

below is the output i recieve

```
//| b1  >#<    12
//| b1  > <    12
```

Question 1) why is `getType` returning 12? This is the strangest data type I've ever heard of.

Question 2) (possibly answered by Q1) why does the `if(line(7)=="#")` statement never returns true?

Comment: You don't use `==` to compare strings. use `.equals` method.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh In Scala you do (it calls `equals`).

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh that is not true in **Scala** but in freaking **Java**. - Scalaflow, can you please format and indent your code so it is readable? Anyways, I believe the problem is that `line(7)` reruns a `Char` and not an `String`. Use `line(7) == '7'`

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Yes. But that `==` allows `nulls` to pass without notice, which is not desired in most situations (just my personal experience). And for me, it has become a hard rule learned by lots of failures. I thought that this was a more common burn among Scala devs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your questions in reverse order:

Question 2. Because `line` is a `String`, `line(7)` is a `Char` which is never equal to a `String`. You want to compare it with `'#'` instead.

Question 1. Because of the above, this calls [`Char.getType`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/Char.html#getType:Int) method which

> [Returns a value indicating a character's general category.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getType(char))

(not that you can find it from Scala's own documentation). You probably wanted [`getClass`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()) instead.

Comment: Isn't there a compiler warning about comparing incompatible types?

Comment: Actually there should be, yes.